# Node.js converting date string to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix-timestamp

I'm attempting to convert a Date String to a unix timestamp in Node.js.

My code below works perfectly on my client but when I run it on my server I get an error:

> (node:19260) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: input.substring is not a function

My code:

```
function dateParser(input) {
    // function is passed a date and parses it to create a unix timestamp

    // removing the '.000' from input
    let finalDate = input.substring(0, input.length - 4);
    return new Date(finalDate.split(' ').join('T')).getTime();
}
```

Example of my input would be **2017-09-15 00:00:00.000**

So why does the above work on my client but not in Node, and how would I duplicate the functionality in node?

Comment: How is `dateParser()` being called and what is being passed to it?

Comment: Could you `console.log(typeof input)` ?

Comment: @TGrif object is returned

Comment: As you're not passing a string but a date object to your dateParser function, you get a _input.substring is not a function_ error.
You could use `Date.parse()` to get the Unix timestamp representation of the date.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a date object from your input DateTime string and then use `getTime()` and divide the result with 1000 to get the UNIX timestamp.

```js
var unixTimestamp = Math.floor(new Date("2017-09-15 00:00:00.000").getTime()/1000);
console.log(unixTimestamp);
```

Comment: For anybody converting the current time to a unix timestamp you should use `Math.floor`, otherwise you'll be generating a time ever so slightly in the future. In fact, I think `Math.floor` is always more appropriate as it's usually desirable to discard the precision.

Answer (score 3):

I will recommend using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to handle the dates. Using momentjs you could do:

```
moment().unix(); // Gives UNIX timestamp
```

If you already have a date and want to get the UNIX timestamp relative to that date, you could do:

```
moment("2017-09-15 00:00:00.000").unix(); // I have passed the date that will be your input 
// Gives out 1505413800
```

It gets very productive when handling date/time using momentjs.

Answer (score 0):

A Unix timestamp is the number of seconds from a specific date. The Javascript function getTime() returns the number of milliseconds from the same specific date til the date you specified.

So, if you divide the result of your function by number 1000 you will get the Unix timestamp and convert from milliseconds to seconds. Don't forget to ignore decimal places.

The error message you are receiving is because the value of input is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

2 options with slightly different results if system timezone is not set to UTC

Option 1 - Ignores system timezone

```
console.log(Math.floor(new Date("2020-01-01").getTime()/1000));

> 1577836800
```

Option 2 ("moment.js") - Timestamp will differ with system timezone

```
console.log(moment('2020-01-01').unix());

> 1577854800
```